# How to return type as <class, int>?

Tags: python, types

```
def type_tup(a):
    type_tub = (a, type(a))
    return type_tub

a=3
print(type(a))
type_tup(a)
```

For the above code, type_tup(a) returns as (3, int). How can I make it return (3, ), like the output with "print"?

Thanks!

Comment: `type_tub = (a, )`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: You can achieve this by using `repr`: `type_tub = (a, repr(type(a)))`. `repr` returns the representation of the object as a string.